# Responding to an apology (no problem, don't worry about it, etc.)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

What are the common ways of responding to an apology? In English, if someone says "Sorry I didn't/couldn't do (whatever)" (or simply bumps into you accidentally and says "sorry") we'd say things like:

- No problem.
- It's fine.
- Don't worry about it.
- It's cool.
- No worries.

What phrases can be used for this situation in Spanish?

Comment: `No es nada` is what I hear quite often in series and película, most times accompanied with an `hombre, chico, tía, etc.`

Comment: *No hay de que* is another possibility, meaning "no need (to apologize)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say the following:

- No hay problema = *No problem.*
- No importa. = *It's fine.*
- No te preocupes. = *Don't worry about it.*
- Está bien. = *It's cool.*

As to "*no worries*" I can't think of a proper translation. But anothe alternative is "*tranquilo*".

Comment: "No worries" is just the Australian colloquial way to say exactly the same as "no problem".

Comment: It's not just Australian. It's used across the UK, too

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it is universally accepted, but "no es nada" is very usual:

> Disculpe, no quise pisarle la nariz
>
> No te preocupes, no es nada

Answer (score 3):

In Spain at least:

If someone bumps into you accidentally and says "sorry", you can answer "sorry" too (Perdón), or "no problem" (No pasa nada) or just "Nada". But answering "tranquilo" could sound like "hey, relax man" or "keep it easy" if it's not said politely :)

Answering an apology for something more formal would be just the offerings on the previous reply.

Comment: Glad to be of help!